# drawing image in jframe game

Tags: java, jframe

I'm having some trouble getting an image drawn in java. There are no console errors and it prints 'drawing'. I believe I am loading the image wrong but I can't figure out the right way. If someone could tell me the correct way that would be great.

```
      package platformer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Image;

public class test2 extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

    int Width = 1000;
    int Height = 600;
    private static Image offScreenBuffer;// needed for double buffering graphics
    private Graphics offScreenGraphics;// needed for double buffering graphics
    private BufferedImage[] img = new BufferedImage[1];

    public test2() {

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);
                g.drawImage(img[0],0,0,null);
    }

    public void timer1() {
        int delay = 30; // milliseconds
        new Timer(delay, this).start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, Exception {

        test2 test2 = new test2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("platformer");
        frame.setSize(test2.Width, test2.Height);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(test2);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.addKeyListener(test2);
        test2.init();
        test2.timer1();
        // What to do after the program starts
        while (true) {
            test2.repaint();

        }
    }

    public void init() {


        try {
            URL url = new URL("platform.png");
            img[0] = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }


    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }



}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but since you only have one image, you don't need an array. Just do `private Image img;`.

Comment: I also suggest avoid ending names with numbers. Class names should be more meaningful. If you are ending variable names with numbers, then you really need an `List` or an `array.

Comment: The code you posted here is complicated by all the extra stuff involved in your game. I suggest creating another class as an example which only loads an image and displays it. If you still have trouble edit this question with your simplified version.

Comment: I cut out the junk

Comment: You don't need a loop in main. You just need to show the JFrame. Also you can cut all the event handling.

Comment: Also offScreenBuffer shouldn't be static.

Comment: I just need help getting the image displayed.

Comment: In fact both offScreenBuffer and offScreenGraphics should be local variables in paint().

Comment: Okay I did that but is how I'm leading the image in the init method correct?

Comment: You still have extra stuff in your code that is irrelevant to displaying an image. Also you need to make the changes suggested in my answer.

Comment: Please just look at the init method for now

Comment: I just noticed that init() ignores some exceptions. Don't do that. Instead add the everyone to the throws clause.

Comment: I suggest using File instead of URL.

Comment: What do you mean  by add the everything?

Comment: Where did I say that?

Comment: " Instead add the everyone to the throws clause."

Answer (score 0):

Swing has an infinite loop that does event handling for you. You don't need the `while(true)` loop. You should call `frame.setVisible(true)` after all of your UI is configured. I mean that it should be the last thing in `main()`. Also, you should do this on the UI thread with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

So main() should look like

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, Exception {

        test2 test2 = new test2();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("platformer");
        frame.setSize(test2.Width, test2.Height);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.green);
        frame.add(test2);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.addKeyListener(test2);
        test2.init();
        test2.timer1();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
    }
```

However, the main problem is the try... catch in init() which ignores exceptions. You should never leave a catch empty. At the very least you should print a stacktrace. Better yet, add the appropriate exceptions to the methods throws clause like this:

```
    public void init() throws IOException {
            URL url = new URL("platform.png");
            img[0] = ImageIO.read(url);
    }
```

Note if a problem occurs, you will know about it immediately.

Comment: I don't get how to gets the image to show, I can draw rectangles fine but the image won't work.

Comment: @MickDom I suggest removing the whole `if (level == 1)` and replace it with a simple `g.drawImage()` first. When you do this what happens?

Comment: @MickDom Also, my apologies for the error in my code snippet here. I have fixed it.

Comment: @MickDom I also just found that you already call `setVisible()`. I suggest moving this to the end of `main()` and don't call `game.repaint()` at all.

Comment: @MickDom As I say in my most recent edit, this should be at the end of `main()`. Also be sure to remove the `frame.setVisible()` line which you already have.

Comment: Updated my code in OP. Image doesn't load and doesn't refresh anymore.